# Why React Lazy Loading generating one big chunk?

Tags: reactjs, performance, webpack, lazy-loading, loadable-component

I'm trying to increase my website performance.
I did a lot of research and found a `code splitting`.
I have tried both `React Lazy load` and `Loadable Components`. I have got a result but not that big.

I think the problem is the big chunk which is 600 kb.
For getting where it comes from I've named all my chunks which I'm lazy loading. And all the chunks are renamed expect that big one.

[Check my network and u will see that chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5t5q.png)

Can somebody explain me what it is and how it is generated ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: It is properly all the third party npm libraries you are using like react, lodash etc.

Comment: [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) is a useful tool for figuring out which source files are contributing to which chunk